# Playing sound from SDCard with MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Let me explain clearly:

1. I have folder named "Sounds" and there are some .ogg files to play.
2. I got the folder path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + mySoundsPath;`.
3. I got all list from that folder and save it to array: `List<String> soundList;`

My question is:

1. How to call the sound from `soundList` that i created so they all can be played??
2. Should it need to decoded(like images, decoded to Bitmap)??

Sorry for my grammar.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below link for the reference 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

and you can try small code sample as well

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

Comment: thanks for the reference..
i used my logic from that reference..
MediaPlayer just can take from resID and Uri..
it's impossible if i use resID, so i try to convert the string to Uri..
and it works..
and thanks again for your reference.. :D

Answer (score 0):

public void play(String path) {
                count++;
                playFile=path;

```
            //showNotification();
        new NotificationPanel(activity);


            if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                Log.d("*****begin*****", "playing");
                stopPlaying();
                 Log.d("*****begin*****", "stoping");
              } else{
                 Log.d("*****begin*****", "nothing");
              }


            Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse(path);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activity, myUri1);            
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }

        private void stopPlaying() { 
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
           } 
        }
```